# Android network connection. Can write data but cannot read it. Using QT Server

Tags: android, c++, qt

I'm following a modified example I found online in order to comunicate with a program that I've written in my PC (Using Qt). When the data is received, the Qt function is really simple

```
void FileTransferServer::on_dataReady(){

    QByteArray buffer = socket->readAll();
    ui->teLog->append("Received: " + QString(buffer));
    QByteArray data;
    QString msg = "Soy Qt!!";
    data = msg.toLatin1();
    qint32 value =  socket->write(data);
    ui->teLog->append("Sending reply of " + QString::number(value) + " bytes");

}
```

In android I've implemented an AsyncTask for the TCP Client. The code for the main function of the client is below.:

```
public void run(){
        try {
            //here you must put your computer's IP address.
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_ADDRESS);

            System.err.println("Attempting connection...");

            //create a socket to make the connection with the server
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_PORT);

            try {

                //send the message to the server
                out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

                System.err.println("Connection successful attempting to send message");

                //To receive messages
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                int i = 0;
                while (i < 10) {
                    i++;
                    out.println("This is Android!!");

                    // Waiting for response.
                    boolean msgRead = false;
                    String msg;

                    while (!msgRead) {

                        System.err.println("Attempting to read a message");

                        msg = in.readLine();

                        System.err.println("Message received: " + msg);

                        if (msg != null) {
                            //output.append("Reply: " + msg);
                            System.err.println("Reply: " + msg);
                            msgRead = true;
                        }

                    }

                }

                System.err.println("All done!");


            } catch (Exception e) {

                System.err.println("Error on sending message: " + e.getMessage());

            } finally {
                //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
                // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
                socket.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.err.println("Error on connection: " + e.getMessage() + " And also " + e.toString());

        }
```

My problem is that even though I can send data from the PC to my phone, it does not work the other way around.

Here my console output (for my phone)

```
09-06 20:54:32.619 31231-31245/? W/System.err: Attempting connection...
09-06 20:54:32.629 31231-31245/? W/System.err: Connection successful attempting to send message
09-06 20:54:32.629 31231-31245/? W/System.err: Attempting to read a message
```

While the output of my simple Qt App is:

```
Accepted connection from ::ffff:192.168.1.107. Local address is ::ffff:192.168.1.110
Received: This is Android!!

Sending reply of 8 bytes
```

However the program hangs on attempting to read the message, as shown above.

Also when I Quit Qt Program I get a ton of these

```
09-06 20:56:39.569 31231-31245/cmp.cmpreceiver W/System.err: Attempting to read a message
09-06 20:56:39.569 31231-31245/cmp.cmpreceiver W/System.err: Message received: null
```

Can any one tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your payload may be too small to be sent immediately due to [Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) AKA TCP_NODELAY.

Your may need to disable it like this:

```
socket->setSocketOption(QAbstractSocket::LowDelayOption, 1);
```